# Extra data appended to the Y values when issuing `M92` & `M500`

Tags: g-code, calibration, repetier-host, anet-a8

I am still trying to dial in my Anet A8.

The Marlin firmware takes too long to scroll through the axis settings when I change them, so I use Repetier Host instead issuing `M92` followed by `M500`.

I noticed in the log window that X goes in as typed but that Y has a `*75` after the value i input. Can anybody tell me why/what it is for? I suspect I know what it does just no idea why it is doing it.

Answer (score 4):

`*75` is the checksum value, (a method for verifying the integrity of the transmitted information).

[RepRap wiki gcode : checksum](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#.2A:_Checksum)

There is probably an option to not use/disable checksum generation in repetier/slicers, however this may only be advantageous for use with code run from the sdcard as it is extra processing (and probably less relevant when not being transmitted over serial connection. )

Comment: Thanks. Calibration getting closer but not quite right yet. I just wondered if this was a possible source of my X Y problem of circles not being round....grrrr. I will ignore it.